# Recursion template: object<auto_ptr<object>>

Tags: c++

I want the object's pointer (or handle) to be customizable.
So I can sometimes choose using a pointer which may act like a handle with ref counting but in other case just using the raw pointer.

```
template <typename PointerType>
class object
{
public:
    // but the PointerType do need the type it point to...
    typename PointerType<object> _parent;
};

int main()
{
    // i choose using shared_ptr as handle
    // object<std::shared_ptr> a;
    // object<std::shared_ptr> b;
    // a._parent = &b;
    // b._parent = nullptr;
    // or a auto_ptr.......
    // object<std::auto_ptr> a;
    // object<std::auto_ptr> b;
    // a._parent = &b;
    // b._parent = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` are not types!. `std::auto_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>` are. Lines which are commented are wrong.

Comment: i know it but once if i write object<std::auto_ptr<object>> it occurs a recursion error

Comment: `PointerType` must be a `type` and `type` don't take template parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need a template template parameter:

```
template <template <typename...> PointerType>
class object
{
public:
    PointerType<object> _parent;
};
```

with usage similar to:

```
object<std::shared_ptr> a;
a._parent = std::make_shared<object<std::shared_ptr>>();
```